# ASP.NET MVC Interview Questions

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have to interview a guy for an ASP.NET MVC position. Its a short term contract so I need someone who knows it pretty well. Also there is a lot of JQuery involved.

I was thinking of starting with general questions like:

1. What is MVC in general?
2. Why use ASP MVC Framework? Comparison with Webforms.
   .. etc.

But what other questions would you recommend for MVC & JQuery?

Thanks

Comment: Have you heard of MVP and how does MVC match up. What are the benefits of of MVC over MVP.

Comment: Start here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/556995/ASP-NET-MVC-interview-questions-with-answers

Comment: Please refer http://grandhah.blogspot.in/2015/08/mvc-interview-questions.html

Comment: i read below all answer,and i am adding some more 1).In MVC development time need less.   2).your page response time take less.  3).your `model` having `classfile` `view` having   `html+fontend code(.js)` code and `controler' having all logic  code. so, your code are separated so code understanding or farther change    become easy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in my view

- Extension methods(htmlhelpers etc.)
- routing
- model validation (extending to client side with jquery)
- Model binding (custom model binders)
- ORM concepts(L2S,EF etc)
- LINQ
- using sqlMembershiptProvider and sqlRoleProvider with mvc (if u want to use them)

Comment: Maybe add Data Annotations to model validation description. Also I think understanding IoC and Dependency Injection, and perhaps unit testing would be useful.

Comment: though the question was about the asp.net mvc but there are chances that somebody may ask "where this .ToString() comes from" `:)`

Answer (score 3):

The great thing about MVC is that it allows you to build patterns into your apps.  For example, by writing base controller classes that encapsulate reusable methods, properties, Action filters, etc.  Or by writing Helpers.  Or Attributes.  Or better still, combining them all into mini frameworks.

I would emply someone who thought that way.  If they think like that, they understand MVC.

Everything else can be learnt.

Answer (score 2):

Someone who has experience with MVC should understand how to use **Action Filters** and **Input Builder Templates**. Also, if they're going to be developing in MVC, I think knowing about **jQuery** and client side UI tools is important since there are no built in web controls to work with. I'd also listen for them to mention **MVCContrib** or **FubuMVC**. Since MVC promotes **separation of concerns** the developer should understand what that is.

Comment: I know MVC devs who have no idea what MVCContrib  or FubuMVCV is.  Knowing FUBU is especially odd considering it is an alternative MVC framework.  Do you know there is a Spring MVC framework thats been out forever?  Am I supposed to know about that?

Comment: @jfar Only if you like developing in XML. :P Seriously though, the reason I mentioned those frameworks is that a developer who has spent any amount of time reading .Net oriented tech blogs has surely heard of them. Personally I don't use either, but I've stolen many concepts from them that make my life as an MVC developer easier.

Comment: @Ryan, I don't think you understand my point.  I know talented MVC developers who have no idea what MVCContrib or FubuMVC are.  You'd essentially be changing your requirements from "people that know MVC" to "people that know MVC and read blogs".  Considering that only a fraction of developers read blogs your answer would restrict the potential worker pool to a harmful level.

Comment: @jfar Reading blogs should be a good indicator that a developer is dedicated to continuing their education. I don't care how talented you are, everybody benefits from hearing/reading new ideas. When we interview candidates we always look for people who are involved in the community and open source because in our experience it's a reliable indicator of future performance. Plus we can go look at their code.

Comment: I work with MVC every day for the last year and I'm not sure what "Input Builder Templates" are. What are they? I just did a Google search on it and it yielded nothing. I don't think asking for things outside of standard MVC is a good way to rate someone.

Comment: @Paul Mendoza I'm talking about the `Html.EditorFor(x => x...)` etc. If you haven't tried them out, do so. They increase productivity like you wouldn't believe. This link is an introduction to the concept. MS has their own implementation in MVC 2+. http://lostechies.com/erichexter/2009/06/09/opinionated-input-builders-for-asp-net-mvc-using-partials-part-i/